# How to sample from a vector without repeating?

Tags: r

Good afternoon !

I need to sample elements from a vector but without repeating.
This means if i have a vector of n elements , i will take an element each time by random & i will store the element in a table. The next time my initial table will not contain the element selected before.

ex :

```
a = c(1,2,0,7,5)
sample(a,1) give 5 for example. 
print(a) ; a now should contain only 1 , 2 , 0 , 7.
```

I wish my question is clear.
Thank you for help !

Comment: `sample(a, replace=FALSE)` will shuffle the initial array, then just start from the front and work towards the end.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to sample an index value and subset based on it:

```
a <- c(1, 2, 0, 7, 5)

set.seed(123)
ind <- sample(seq_along(a), 1)

a[ind]
a[-ind]
```

Comment: Hmmm, looks familiar (to my comment). Code golf: `ind <- sample(length(a), 1)`.

Comment: @r2evans sure, the ```a_new``` is largely your comment - there are only so many ways to do it and I don't think the basics need to be credited to others. Still, I will delete that part.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution could be :

```
a = c(1,2,0,7,5)
a=a[!a %in% sample(a,1)] ;
```

will sample the element & delete it.

Comment: If all you need is to remove one element, how about `a <- sample(a, size=length(a)-1)`? (Or is there some other code intended between your two lines here?)

Comment: Yes , but i need also to retrive the value i had sampled.